# Passing TLAs from argocd to jsonnet

Tags: argocd, jsonnet

Trying to understand [passing TLAs to my jsonnet file](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/jsonnet/#build-environment) with argocd. This is part of my argocd application.yaml which compiles the kube-prometheus manifests straight from my main.jsonnet file. I want to create 2 kube-prometheus apps in argocd (prod and nonprod) and I want to pass TLAs to change the ingress host name suffix for each app instance.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: kube-prometheus-nonprod
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    name: ''
    namespace: monitoring
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  source:
    path: kube-prometheus/src
    repoURL: 'https://myrepo.git'
    targetRevision: branch-name
    directory:
      jsonnet:
        tlas:
          - name: npDomainSuffix
            value: np.example.io
      libs:
        - kube-prometheus/vendor/
```

In my main.jsonnet file I have for example:

```
hosts: ['grafana.$(npDomainSuffix)']
```

New to jsonnet and argocd and can't get it to work. Can I use TLAs in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're new to `jsonnet`, I'd recommend using `extVars` instead, as TLA mechanics are somewhat harder to grasp, from the [jsonnet tutorial](https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html#parameterize-entire-config) for the TLA section, you'll find that your jsonnet code needs an entry function with arguments named after each top-level-argument name.

Alternatively, using extVars you should be able to do instead:

```
        extVars:
          - name: npDomainSuffix
            value: np.example.io
```

then *anywhere* in your jsonnet code (`extVars` are global)

```
hosts: ['grafana.' + std.extVar('npDomainSuffix')]
```